# Reproducible id generation with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML document that I convert into two documents: one table of contents, and one the actual content.

I use something like the following template to generate an id for my XML tags, so I can map the table of contents to my document:

```
<xsl:template match="kop">
  <sometag id="{generate-id(.)}" />
</xsl:template>
```

Processing with Saxon, though, will not create a reliable reproducible id. (e.g., multiple runs will give different ids.)

Is it possible to seed the generator (like I thought I had done by passing the current element into the function), or otherwise generate an id that is guaranteed to be the same every time I run the transformation, like node number in the tree or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your processing allows to use simple numbering of nodes with `xsl:number` like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="kop">
    <xsl:variable name="id">
      <xsl:number level="single" count="kop"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <sometag id="ID{$id}" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With input

```
<root>
  <kop/>
  <kkk/>
  <kop/>
</root>
```

the above XSLT outputs

```
<sometag id="ID1"></sometag>
<sometag id="ID2"></sometag>
```

You can use something like `count="kop|kkk"` to include other elements in numbering (example results in ID3 instead of ID2 in second line).

(I tried it on XsltCake.com with Browser Firefox 25.)

Comment: Thanks! I settled for `<xsl:number level="any"/>`, because `kop` could be nested in any way.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Saxon 9 implementing XSLT 2.0 the right approach is to write one stylesheet processing your `kop` elements twice in different modes, creating two result documents using `xsl:result-document`. On a single run the generated id will be unique and so both files will have the same generated ids for the input elements you process.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I should have said that I want to do dynamic XSLT transformation based on separate server requests. I can't pre-process my XML files like this, but it would be a good solution otherwise!